# Google Analytics Implementation Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, web-analytics, google-analytics

I am looking to implement Google Analytics into a Sharepoint 2013 site. I have my GA tracking code ready to go, and have full access to all master pages in the site. However, after reviewing the answers already posted, I am still unsure of exactly which master page to paste it into (I am fully ok with where in the tags it goes. I have a number of pages identified as master pages in the following configuration:
Content type:
html master page: 4 pages
Master Page: 3 pages
ASP NET Master Page: 3 pages

All of these seem that they could be an option, and no one master page is greyed out indicating it is in use. HOWEVER! I am working in Sharepoint Designer 2013, and when I sort these pages by date modified, I can narrow it down to 2 x html master pages and 2 x asp net master pages, with the 2 html master pages having the blue icon indicating that they have been modified from the site definition. So, pardon my long message, but should I be inserting the GA code to all of these asp and html master pages or just certain pages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally you add the Google Analytics code to the html-master page used by the site collection.  Go to the Site Collection page (top page of the site), get 'Site Settings', and then find 'Master page' under 'Look and Feel'.  Whatever site master page is listed there is the master page you will want to edit.

P.S. -- Let me know if it works.  I've added the GA code to the bottom of the head section of the correct .html file, but it doesn't seem to be translating over to the corresponding .master file.